Cmake function not linked correctly. Function return 0
I'm new to Cmake, and am a bit beaten by it.
In my main project I'm trying to fetchcontent a git Repo and add it to my main project as a lib.
The problem I have is that everything builds fine. however when I call the function int GetVersion(){return 2;} from the LIB, it simply returns 0.
I build a .elf for an STM32 Microcontroller using STM32CUBEIDE.
I already made a project without IDE and made .exe and... it works as expected it prints 3...
There are no errors or warning other that a = unused. But the optimizer is turned of and i can step through the code.
Since everything builds fine, I have a feeling it is not linking well.
Am I missing anything, what can I do to debug this further?
//Main.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ringbuff.h"

int main(void)
{
    static int a = 1;
    a = GetVersion(); // after this call a = 0
    for(;;);
}

//ringbuff.c from the lib.  The header contains: 'int GetVersion2();'
#include "ringbuff.h"

int GetVersion()
{
    return 3;
}

cMakelists of Main project. Everything is standard cmaketemplate from the IDE, I've added the part inbetween the Import Lib comments
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set (PROJECT_NAME             "CM7")

# LIST SOURCE FILES HERE
set (PROJECT_SOURCES
    Startup/startup_stm32h755zitx.s
    Sources/system_stm32h7xx_dualcore_boot_cm4_cm7.c
    Sources/main.c
    Sources/syscalls.c
    Sources/sysmem.c
    )

# LIST COMPILER DEFINITIONS HERE
set (PROJECT_DEFINES
        CORE_CM7
        STM32H755xx
    ) 

# LIST INCLUDE DIRECTORIES HERE
set (PROJECT_INCLUDES
    Sources
      
    #STM32 HAL & CMSIS
    Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
    Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
    Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include
    Drivers/CMSIS/Include
    )

project(${PROJECT_NAME})
enable_language(ASM)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
add_custom_command(TARGET ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE} $<TARGET_FILE:${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}>)

################# Import module #####################
include(FetchContent)
Set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
FetchContent_Declare(
  ringbuff
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/TESTMODULE.git
  GIT_TAG        V0.7
  GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(ringbuff)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${ringbuff_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    PRIVATE ringbuff
)
#####################################################

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE ${PROJECT_DEFINES}
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_INCLUDES}
)

set (CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".elf")
set (CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".a")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mcpu=Cortex-M7 -O0 -std=gnu11 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 --specs=nano.specs -mthumb -Wall")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-T../STM32H755ZITX_FLASH.ld --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map=test.map -Wl,--gc-sections -static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group")
set (CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")

Cmakelist of the ringbuff lib
# Minimum version of CMake required
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

# Project name
project(RingBuffer C)

# Add the source files
add_library(ringbuff STATIC ringbuff.c)


Does add_library work with raw source files and not object files? After all, object files only need to be linked, they're already compiled, while the source isn't. Also, did you step into the function with the debugger? You can add some volatile int writes into the misbehaving function to prevent possible optimizations for testing.

Project(RingBuffer...) ... add_library(ringbuff....) looks suspicious. Shouldn't the name in the add_library be the same as the project name?

@Ilya I Tried both options independently.
I did not put object files into add_library?
However if i directly add the sourcepath of ringbuff to add_library it works as expected.
But then it is compiled by the main cmakelist.
When i added a volatile int in getversion(), it worked as expected and returned 3. And could also step through the function. which it would not let me do without.
Would that mean it optimized away?

@pcmacfarlane I tried changing it all to ringbuff, but did not change anything.

added another function int func(){ return 5;} to the lib, which is not called in the main.
This is enough to get the getversion2() working.
Seems like a ran in a weird edgecase

Well disregard all my comments above...
I forgot to remove, the source from add library.
So adding the source directly did work.
Adding the volatile int to the function did not work.
Adding another function did not work.

Turns out i was missing the set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS " -mthumb") in the cmakelist of the Lib.
